# Express a function as convolution of two function - How to get intuition for the convolution

Tags: intuition, convolution

$$x\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}1-t&0\le t\le 1\\ 1+t&-1\le t\le 0\\ 0&else\end{cases}$$
How can I understand that:
$$x(t)=h(t)*h(t)$$
when:
$$h\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}1&-\frac{1}{2}\le t\le \frac{1}{2}\\ 0&else\end{cases}$$
I am studying to a test and can not really understand the intuition to how I see the convolution from a function.
( it was a question to find Fourier Trasnform, I can do it without convolution, but I wanted to know for me how to get intuition for it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that using the explicit formula -

$x(t) = \int h(s)h(t-s)ds $

Since $h$ is simply an indicator function of the interval $[-1/2, 1/2]$, then $h(s)h(t-s)$ is also an indicator function! It is an indicator of the intersection between the intervals $[-1/2, 1/2]$ and $[t-1/2, t+1/2]$ (both of length $1$). This is the set ${ -1/2 \le s , t-s \le 1/2} $, which can be re-written as

${ max(-1/2, t-1/2) \le s \le min(1/2, t+1/2) }$

as long as $t-1/2 \le 1/2$ (the left endpoint of the first interval is less than the right endpoint of the second) and $-1/2 \le t+1/2$ (and vice versa) - i.e., $-1\le t\le 1$. Otherwise the intervals are disjoint and their intersection is the empty set (which its indicator's integral is 0).

If $t \le 0$, the LHS is $-1/2$, and if $t \ge 0$, the RHS is $1/2$.

To sum up, we got that the integrand is the indicator function of the interval -

$[-1/2, t+1/2]$ for $t \le 0$

$[t-1/2, 1/2]$ for $t \ge 0$

The integral of an indicator is simply the length of the interval, which is $1+t$ in the first case, and $1-t$ in the second case. To sum up, we got the exact answer you have written down.

Intuitively, I like to think of a convolution by looking at the formula directly - For each $t$, I'm multiplying $h(s)$ and $h(t-s)$, thinking of one as a "slider" of the values of $h$ starting from $0$ and going to the right, and the other as a "slider" starting from $t$ and going to the left. Looking at this graphically makes sense in my opinion.

Comment: Hi, I understand the solution, but I am trying to think, without seeing the solutions
I see $x(t)$, how  my mind crosses through the thought of convoluion at that interval?
Sadly I cant really understand what you said at the end :(

Comment: You can think of two "steps" of length $1$, which are the graph of $h$. One travels "right" ($h(s)$), and one travels "left" ($h(t-s)$).

The integral is the area "common" to both steps. As one moves to the left and one to the right, at the "extremities", the intersection is empty and it's length is $0$, after some movement they start to intersect, and then the intersection slowly grows (this is the $t-1$ part, which has a positive slope) until they coincide (at $t=0$, where $h(s)$ and $h(-s)$ have the same graph) and then it starts to decrease (the negative slope, $1-t$).

Comment: Oh I see, thanks!